# how to fix the error "package weka does not exist" in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, weka

I want to use weka with java.

I downloaded and installed weka and also downloaded the api weka-oneclass.jar. I am using netbeans IDE and so added this external jar file. But now when I start importing this package of weka, it says weka package does not exist. The package is listed in the classpath too. Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you see it in the Libraries section down the left hand side of the main screen in Netbeans?

If you right click on your project, and go to the libraries section, is your jar file listed in the compile tab?

Finally, if you open up the jar file in the libraries section, does it have the classes your after?

If thats all correct, I would try clean and build your project again.